# Implication Operation $\rightarrow$

Tags: logic, notation, terminology

Apologies in advance if it is stupid question, but I am learning it myself which means I may not have the prerequisites knowledge. please help.

I am reading "Introduction to the theory of computation (third edition)" by Michael Sipser. On page 15, on the second paragraph,  "Finally, the implication operation is designed by the symbol $\rightarrow$ and its 0 if its first operand is 1 and its second operand is 0; otherwise, $\rightarrow$ is 1."

I understand what it means. I don't see how / where in math we would do that?  the boolean is 0 if its first operand is 1 and its second operand is 0. Can you please one example in math / computer science ? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: For a start, what is wrong with the example you have in front of you, namely Sipser's book? The concept of [material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) is ubiquitous in mathematics and computer science. If you'd asked "why" rather than "how" or "where", that would have been a more interesting question.

Comment: I would not claim any thing wrong while I understand it. but thank you for the material implication link, which provides some background information for me.

Comment: The answer to "how" is clear and the answer to "where" is given by the book you are reading and the link I provided. That gives you more than "one" example. So what is your question?

Comment: can you please points out where I can find the "how" and "where" usage of  Implication Operation → in the book?

Comment: It's in front of you! In the book. Please read your own question and remember that your book is part of the maths and computer science literature.

Comment: @Rob Arthan,  Yes my book is part of the maths and computer science literature and asking for help to understand them is part of my learning. Thank you for the encouragement. Hope your time of signing up the account and asking and answering questions server you well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that there are many students like you who have difficulty with material (logical) implication. How, for example, can we infer that $A\implies B$ is true knowing only that $A$ is false? Or knowing only that $B$ is true. In fact, we can make such inferences. These are well accepted methods of proof in mathematics or wherever we are dealing with logical propositions that are known to be unambiguously either true or false. It seems to be inevitable. It's not just some arbitrary convention that you must simply accept and memorize.

You may find my recent blog posting on [material implication](http://dcproof.com/IfPigsCanFly.html) to be useful. There, I derive or attempt to justify each entry in the truth table for implication.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operation, $p\to q$, is $1$ if the first operand ($p$) is $0$, or if the first is $1$ and the second operand ($q$) is $1$.   The operation is only designated $0$ if the first operand is $1$ while the second is $0$.

This is summarised by the following "truth table": $${\begin{array}{|c:c|c|}\hline ~p~ & ~q~ & p\to q\\[0.5ex]\hline 1 & 1 & 1\\[0.5ex]\hdashline 1 & 0 & 0 \\[0.5ex] \hdashline 0 & 1 & 1 \\[0.5ex] \hdashline 0 & 0 & 1 \\[0.5ex]\hline \end{array}}$$

And why not?   We want the symbol to capture the notion that $p$ implies $q$.   That it is a promise that $q$ is $1$ when $p$ is $1$.   Such a 'promise' is only not held up when $p$ is $1$ but $q$ is not.   So that is the *only* row in the truth table we mark the operation with a value of $0$ .

Comment: To the proposer: The idea is that we assign the value $v(S)=1$ to $ S$ if $S$ is true and assign to $S$ the value $v(S)=0$ if $S$ is false.  Observe that in arithmetic modulo $2$ we have $(p\implies q) \iff  v(p)+v(p)v(q)=0.$.... BTW the LaTex for "implies" is \implies, and the Latex for "iff" is \iff. Sometimes you can use \to for "implies".

Comment: @Graham Kemp, as we are using the the "promise" idea. When p is 0 and q is 1, can you help me understand how the promise held up ?, In this case is  p implies q.  With p is "false" as denoted as 0, although q is 1, then why the result of  0 implies 1 is 1 then ?

Comment: @Others I have promised that $q=1$ if $p=1$.  However, you checked and found that $p=0$ and $q=1$.  Well, can you say my promise is broken?